# How do I copy data from one excel sheet to another excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

This code just opens the source file but doesn't copy anything from it. I want to copy the data from my source file and paste it to the destination file.

```
Sub copy()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("Source File")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Destination File")

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This code just opens the source file but doesn't copy anything from it. I want to copy the data from my source file and paste it to the destination file.

Comment: please edit your question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: Both the files are opening.

Comment: both are enable for editing mode and having full control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `.Value` ant the end of your line:

```
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Or Try:

```
y.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = x.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
```

I guess you don't have Sheet1 in both workbook, so lets try different notation.

Try debugging your code with:

```
msgbox y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
msgbox x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

I guess your files are not being opened properly.

Comment: Still data is not able to copy from one file to another. It just opens the source file.

Comment: still not able to copy data

Comment: Tested and the code works for me. Are you using Mac or virtual machine? also I added 2 lines for debugging.

Comment: I am using the normal machine(Windows). There are no such errors I can put and both the files are opening properly but nothing is being copied from one to another.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug, doing the following:

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("Source File")
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("Destination File")

    Debug.Print x.Name
    Debug.Print y.Name

    Debug.Print x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value
    Debug.Print y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    Debug.Print x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Address
    Debug.Print y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing happend after putting the above line.

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat - which one?

Comment: .Value is missing, also if you put this line, you are copying destination file data in source file.

Comment: @DavidG. - just put it there :). But in general, it is taken by default.

Comment: @Vityata both the lines.

Comment: @Vityata still it is opening the source file but not getting any data from it.

Comment: What about the debug.prints? Empty lines in the immediate window?